Flask redirect with parameters?
thanks for your assistance. I am building a simple Flask app - I have a user load an Excel file, perform some transformations on it with Pandas, then simply display a "success" message.
I have a route as follows:
@app.route('/success')
def success(filename, total_count):
    return render_template('success.html', fn=filename, count=total_count)

The function performing the data transformations is as follows:
app.route('/upload', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def upload_file():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # check if the post request has the file part
        if 'file' not in request.files:
            flash('No file part')
            return redirect(request.url)
        file = request.files['file']
        if file.filename == '':
            flash('No selected file')
            return redirect(request.url)
        if file and allowed_file(file.filename):
            filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
            file.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename))
            file_type = request.form.get('file type')
            describe_params={"file_name":filename, "input_path":UPLOAD_FOLDER, "file_type":file_type}
            total_vms=describe_import(**describe_params)
            return redirect(url_for('success'), filename, total_vms)

I have validated that the variables 'filename' and 'total_count' are captured accurately.
Finally, my 'success.html' template is as follows:
<html> 
   <head> 
      <title>success</title> 
   </head> 
   <body> 
      <p>File uploaded successfully</p> 
      <p>File Name: {{fn}}</p> 
      <p>Total VMs: {{vms}}</p> 
   </body> 
</html>

No matter what I try, I keep getting errors like "missing 2 positional arguments"
I don't need to build custom URLs for this - I don't need '/success/file/count' - I just would like the success.html template to be updated with those variables.

When you redirect to the success page your flask server returns a 302 response code to the client along with the url that it should redirect to. There is therefore no direct communication between your upload_file route and your success route and information can only be passed between the two routes via the url or a cookie. To my mind passing the variables within the url would be the natural approach with your suggestion of /success//int:count looking like an ideal solution.

Ah - thank you. That explains a lot - this is my first foray into a web app… clearly I haven’t done the homework yet!  I will make some adjustments and try again.

OK - figured it out.  Thanks @EAW for the nudge - I needed to fix just a couple things.
First, I needed to update my app route thusly:
@app.route('/success/<file_name>/<total_count>')
def success(file_name, total_count):
    return render_template('success.html', fn=file_name, count=total_count)

Next, I needed to change the last line of my upload_file function above:
return redirect(url_for('success', file_name=filename, total_count=totalcount))

And lastly I needed to update my html as follows:
<html> 
   <head> 
      <title>success</title> 
   </head> 
   <body> 
      <p>File uploaded successfully</p> 
      <p>File Name: {{fn}}</p> 
      <p>Total Count: {{count}}</p> 
   </body> 
</html>


Also, I cleaned up and ensured the variables were consistent (doh!).  Rookie error.
I'm on my way - appreciate the assistance!
